# Can not edit the text of a JTextField inside a JPanel within a JWindow

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jwindow

[image]

This is in continuation of my previous question where I asked how to place something in the system tray.
After some help from the community, I could do that. However what I am unable to do is to change the text of the `JTextField` in the `JWindow`.

The `JWindow` has a `JPanel` and everything is placed within the `JPanel`, including the `JTextField` of **Remind Mt At**. However I am unable to type anything in it even though `setEditable(true)`.
The `JTextField` receives events properly as it is supposed to be white when the mouse enters and go back to default color when mouse exits.

Is there any workaround for this?

---

### SSCCE

```
package demo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

import example.Kernel32;

public class SSCCE {
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    JWindow window = new JWindow();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    int remindMeAt = 55;
    Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS batteryStatus = new Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS();

    Clip buzzer;
    AudioInputStream in;

    JLabel ACLineStatus = new JLabel();
    JLabel batteryCharge = new JLabel();
    JTextField enterReminder = new JTextField(3);
    Color defaultColor;

    String onACPower;
    String charge;
    String status;

    boolean keepLooping = true;

    boolean doRemind = true;
    boolean isCharging;
    boolean aboveThreshold;
    boolean remindedOnce = false;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SSCCE();
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public SSCCE(){
        if(SystemTray.isSupported()){
            setupGUI();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setupGUI(){
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            InputStream in = BatteryBeeperSystemTray.class.
                    getResourceAsStream("/images/battery_smaller.png");
            TrayIcon t = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(in));
            t.setToolTip("BatteryBeeper");
            SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(t);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        defaultColor = window.getBackground();

        Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetSystemPowerStatus(batteryStatus);
        onACPower = batteryStatus.getACLineStatusString();
        charge = batteryStatus.getBatteryLifePercent();

        if(onACPower.equalsIgnoreCase("offline")){
            onACPower = "Battery";
        }else{
            onACPower = "AC Power";
            charge = "---";
        }

        ACLineStatus.setText(onACPower);
        ACLineStatus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        ACLineStatus.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Operating On"));

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 7;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        panel.add(ACLineStatus,gbc);

        batteryCharge.setText(charge);
        batteryCharge.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Current " +
                "Charge"));
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(batteryCharge,gbc);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));


        gbc.gridy++;
        enterReminder.setEditable(true);
        enterReminder.requestFocusInWindow();
        enterReminder.setText(Integer.toString(remindMeAt));
        enterReminder.addMouseListener(new TextHandler());
        enterReminder.setBackground(window.getBackground());
        enterReminder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Remind Me" +
                " At"));
        panel.add(enterReminder,gbc);

        window.add(panel);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);


    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void checkIfReminderChanged(){
        //TODO DEFINE
    }   

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class TextHandler extends MouseAdapter{
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            enterReminder.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            enterReminder.setBackground(defaultColor);
            checkIfReminderChanged();
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

---

### What you also need

```
package example;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import java.util.*;

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    public Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);

    /**
     * @see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373232.aspx
     */
    public class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS extends Structure {
        public byte ACLineStatus;
        public byte BatteryFlag;
        public byte BatteryLifePercent;
        public byte Reserved1;
        public int BatteryLifeTime;
        public int BatteryFullLifeTime;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
            fields.add("ACLineStatus");
            fields.add("BatteryFlag");
            fields.add("BatteryFullLifeTime");
            fields.add("BatteryLifePercent");
            fields.add("BatteryLifeTime");
            fields.add("Reserved1");
            return fields;
        }

        /**
         * The AC power status
         */
        public String getACLineStatusString() {
            switch (ACLineStatus) {
                case (0): return "Offline";
                case (1): return "Online";
                default: return "Unknown";
            }
        }

        /**
         * The battery charge status
         */
        public String getBatteryFlagString() {
            switch (BatteryFlag) {
                case (1): return "High, more than 66 percent";
                case (2): return "Low, less than 33 percent";
                case (4): return "Critical, less than five percent";
                case (8): return "Charging";
                case ((byte) 128): return "No system battery";
                default: return "Unknown";
            }
        }

        /**
         * The percentage of full battery charge remaining
         */
        public String getBatteryLifePercent() {
            return (BatteryLifePercent == (byte) 255) ? "Unknown" : BatteryLifePercent + "%";
        }

        /**
         * The number of seconds of battery life remaining
         */
        public String getBatteryLifeTime() {
            return (BatteryLifeTime == -1) ? "Unknown" : BatteryLifeTime + " seconds";
        }

        /**
         * The number of seconds of battery life when at full charge
         */
        public String getBatteryFullLifeTime() {
            return (BatteryFullLifeTime == -1) ? "Unknown" : BatteryFullLifeTime + " seconds";
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("ACLineStatus: " + getACLineStatusString() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Flag: " + getBatteryFlagString() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Life: " + getBatteryLifePercent() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Left: " + getBatteryLifeTime() + "\n");
            sb.append("Battery Full: " + getBatteryFullLifeTime() + "\n");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public int GetSystemPowerStatus(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS result);
}
```

Comment: Good Experiment. Can you provide a runnable code in your question. I couldn't find anything wrong in your code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is your "TextHandler" doing?

Comment: @shuangwhywhy it just changes the color of the text field

Comment: @AndrewThompson is this a bug ? `JTextArea` does not work either

Comment: @LittleChild Have a look at my answer.

Comment: the problem might be (don't know the status of the tray popup) that the window is not focusable, hence none of its children can be focusable and never receive keyboard events. To be focusable, the window must be owned by a showing frame (for details, see the api doc).

Comment: @LittleChild You need your JWindow focusable before it can accept any keyboard events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow%28%29) says about `isFocusableWindow()` as below (I added the numbering to outline the points):

> public final boolean ***isFocusableWindow()***
>
> Returns whether this Window can become the focused Window, that is,
>   whether this Window or any of its subcomponents can become the focus
>   owner. For a Frame or Dialog to be focusable, its focusable Window
>   state must be set to true. **For a Window which is not a Frame or
>   Dialog to be focusable,**
>
> i) **its focusable Window state must be set to
>   true,**
>
> ii) **its nearest owning Frame or Dialog must be showing on the
>   screen,**
>
> iii) **and it must contain at least one Component in its focus
>   traversal cycle.**
>
> ***If any of these conditions is not met, then neither
>   this Window nor any of its subcomponents can become the focus owner.***

As you can see, your code doesn't meet the second rule, so your `JWindow` is not focusable. You need to have a `JDialog` or `JFrame` visible on the screen and then you can wrap it with a `JWindow`:

```
new JWindow(frame);
```

Or you may use `JDialog` or `JFrame` directly instead of `JWindow`. If you don't want the window to be decorated, just call [`Frame.setUndecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) or [`Dialog.setUndecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29).

Comment: +1 for digging up the doc _and_ come up with the solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

create the JWindow like this

```
JWindow window = new JWindow(new JFrame(){public boolean isShowing(){return true;}});
```

Comment: +1 for wickedness :-) Wouldn't use in production, though, without digging for side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but the code looks good.  The only suggestion that I have is to use another component that is similar to a `JTextField`.

Try to use a `JTextArea` instead.  Other componets such as `JTextField` and `JTextPane` could also be options. They all exist in the `javax.swing` library, to use it `import javax.swing.*`

Comment: Tried, same result. Looks like a bug to me

Comment: @LittleChild Try placing the `JTextField` component on a "place holder" panel?  Be sure to post an answer if you found a solution I'm interested to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no use of setting "setEditable(true)" because by default setEditable is true in JTextField. What "requestFocusInWindow()" does in your code. I suspect the problem there.. not quite sure...

Comment: `requestFocusInWindow()` automatically moves the blinking cursor to the text field :)